# Email verification using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, email, verification

Whenever a user registers i am sending him an email which contains the link which user needs to click to get verified. I am passing a token in that  link. When the user clicks the link he should get verified but i am not able to do this. I can just retrieve the token from the link but i am unable to find the user in the database and update the value.

Here is my code:

```
router.route('/verify')
.get(isNotAuthenticated, function(req, res){
var verifyToken = req.query.id;
var user =  User.findOne({ 'secretToken': verifyToken });


        if (!user) {
        req.flash('error', 'No user found with this email id, please check your email id or incorrect link');
        res.redirect('/users/register');
        return;
      }

      user.active = true;
      user.secretToken = '';
      user.save();

      req.flash('success', 'Thank you! Now you may login.');
      res.redirect('/users/login');
      res.redirect('login');
```

Comment: http://localhost:5000/users/verify?id=NnqobIFIetTNl9IMNSTG4XcOyNKeTjR8                                  this is my url and i want to extract id from this, I am using this router.route('/verify')
  .get((req, res) =>{

    console.log(req.body.id);


  });                And this is coming as undefined

Comment: One of the answers solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try using promise to do this instead of assignment.

```
User.findOne({ 'secretToken': verifyToken })
.then(user => {
  // do something with user
})
.catch(err => {
  // do something with error
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JWT to validate your routes you can:

1 - Generate the link verification with one "hash value"(token), save this **token** in the user document (user collection).

```
send the link e.g. "https://site/user/verify?token=3f0621f7e4c41ece51926a40cee4dae0be65ct7"
```

2 - Disable the security for this route:

```
app.use(jwt({secret: process.env.SECRET}).unless({path: ['/users/verify']}));
```

3 - Receive the request to verify the user:

```
router.put('/verify', bodyParser.json(), function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const user = userController.verify(req.query.token);
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

4 - Find and update the user(as verified):

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      token: token,
    },{$set:{verified:true}})
    .then((result) => {
      return result;
    }).catch((err) => {
      //throw error
    });
```

If you need to wait the update for execute other sttufs, you can use async/wait: [Async/Await Tutorial](https://javascript.info/async-await)